# referencing an Mutable array from ClassA to Class B

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class

could someone help me reference an array from a different class.

here is ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *theArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *theArray;

-(NSMutableArray *) pleaseReturnTheArray;

@end
```

ClassA.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize theArray;

...

-(NSMutableArray *) pleaseReturnTheArray {

return theArray; 

}
```

and here is ClassB.m (i want to reference ClassA array, i have #import "MapView.h" into this class, this is a different view that gets pushed onto the screen)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

//first test
ClassA *firstTest = [[ClassA alloc] init];    
NSMutableArray *firstTestArray = [firstTest.theArray mutableCopy];    
NSLog(@"first test - %@", firstTestArray);

//second test
NSMutableArray *secondTestArray = [firstTest pleaseReturnTheArray];   
NSLog(@"second Test - %@", secondTestArray);

...
```

the result in NSLog i get is ...

```
first test - (null)
second Test - (null)
```

I am sure i have used one of these methods before and it has worked fine. Is it something to do with the fact that ClassB is a different view pushed by a tab bar controller?

any help would be appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess here is that you are not initializing theArray to a real array in your init method of ClassA. By default it will be nil. So the mutableCopy will also be nil as is shown in your output. Or perhaps adding this line of code after allocating firstTest would help:

```
firstTest.theArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",nil];
```

Also the pleaseReturnTheArray method is redundant with the theArray getter. You might as well write the following line of code instead:

```
NSMutableArray *secondTestArray = firstTest.theArray;
```

Note that because you are taking a mutable copy for firstTestArray, firstTestArray and secondTestArray will be equal but they will not be the same arrays. That means that if you add something in firstTestArray it won't show up in secondTestArray and vice versa.

Comment: in classA theArray is initialised like this:

    theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

then i added objects to it in a loop.

I only want a pointer to the array and not a copy, i did the copy just to see if it did anything.

Comment: What do you get if you put NSLog(@"firstTest.theArray = %@",firstTest.theArray); just after allocating your object?

Comment: That says that something in the init method is setting your array to nil. Without more context it's difficult to say at this point. Perhaps you can add your init method to the above code.

Comment: i have changed the array in classA to theArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",nil];

Comment: I suggest that you trace the execution line by line from the moment of allocating firstTest to the following NSLog. There should be a point where you are assigning nil to your member variable.

Comment: could it be something to do with me passing the values from one tab bar view to another?